# Angularjs installation using bower

Tags: angularjs, meteor

In my country some social websites and some other sites are blocked. For example meteor.com, codecademy.com, bower.herokuapp.com, etc are not accessed. When I tried to install packages using command 'bower install', it gives following errors:

```
bower angular#~1.4.7         
EAI_AGAIN Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular 
failed: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN bower.herokuapp.com:443
```

Similarly meteor deployment not work, it gives connection error.

Is there any way to install them?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to install bower components using proxy. The code worked for me is as follows:

```
{
  "directory": "library",
  "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com",
  "proxy":"http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY_IP>:<PROXY_PORT>/",
  "https-proxy":"http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY_IP>:<PROXY_PORT>/"
}
```

I am using Win 7 and chrome and also git bash. Here few things need to be cleared. This takes me huge time to find the actual data regarding the user name, password, proxy IP and Port. I will describe it step by step so that every learners can easily grasp the messages:

1. Create a file in the notepad named .bowerrc in the login folder; You can go there by typing at Start>Run>%UserProfile% and press OK.
2. Type above code in the .bowerrc file with the following changes:

   Replace `<USERNAME>` with your internet connection user ID or login ID
   Replace `<PASSWORD>` with your internet connection password or login password.
   Replace `<PROXY_IP> and <PROXY_PORT>` with the working proxy IP address and its port number.

   **Note: There should be no angle brackets.**
3. Proxy IP should be different than your own IP.
4. Before using any proxy IP and port you should check it is working by changing your proxy IP and port.
5. You can go through this link to know the details of proxy settings at
6. From this proxy settings you will get Proxy IP and Port.
7. Recheck all the input so that all are correct and save and close the file.
8. Open git bash and change directory to the project file and type command and hit enter, in my case, git bash command:[description here](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Proxy-Settings)

> a@a-PC MINGW32 /d/conFusion
>
> $ bower install

9. It worked like magic.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that. If you could access https://angularjs.org/, one option is to download it directly there. Alternatively, you could google `angular cdn`, and see if any of the options work for you.

Comment: Yes, I could access https://angularjs.org/ and downloaded the minified file but without installing them are they worked properly?

Comment: There are two steps: 1) download the file, 2) reference it in your `script` tag. Once you download it, it will exist in your local file system, there's no "installation". Check out this video I made about how this works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xz70im79L_M